# Stuck in Shadowrun Returns NTSB Warehouse Part 2

Tags: shadowrun-returns

[image: stuck]

So I entered the NTSB warehouse. There were several mercs in there. While I was fighting the first group, one of the mercs randomly takes off running and enters a side room, sealing himself in behind a door that I can't open. I killed every other merc on the entire map and I can't find a key or any other way to open the door. And I can't get out of combat mode until he dies.

So basically I am perma-stuck unless I load a savegame, or unless I'm missing something. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a way to get into that room either. I didn't notice a vent either, for a Rigger's bot to sneak through.

You may well need to rewind your save back to the checkpoint of entering the warehouse.

Comment: Yep, this appears to be a bug. I struggled with it a long while then decided I'd just reload my save, and post back here if I could reproduce the issue again. I killed the Ork Shadow runner first on my second attempt, and was able to beat this quest. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hey that room with the maintenance panel. You can get in there with a magnetic screw driver you find by sending a drone or summon into the room to the south-east. Theres a large hangar with 2 piles of items, where you got shoes and stuff from.

Theres a window to the right of a door you can't open but a dialogue lets you send bot through it and inside is the screwdriver.

Hope this helps you or next person who comes along. If you don't have a drone or spirit then I don't know how you reach it. Goodluck ;)

Comment: I guess you can't even be in there without having a spirit because Shannon has two talismans in her inventory that can summon a thing. But I'm a decker/samurai and I didn't bring along a rigger, so I guess the only way to do that would've been Shannon, if it let her summon inside that room. Not sure exactly where you're talking about as far as the location of the screwdriver but I probably would have found it eventually if I used the summon correctly. Thanks for the heads up.